# height of Jquery UI dialogue

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I am creating a Jquery UI dialogue like this:

```
 function CloseDisputeDialog() {        
        $("#dispute_form").html("@Html.Raw(closingMsg)");        
        $("#dispute_form").dialog("addbutton", "Close", function() {
            $("#dispute_res").val("close");             
            $("#dispute_form").dialog("close");            
        });
    }
```

in asp.net MVC 3 Razor view. I want to set the height of this dialogue to auto. How can I do this ?

Please suggest. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

E.g. using the option [height](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-height):

```
$("#dispute_form").dialog("option", "height", "auto");
```

Also you can set this option on init.

```
$("#dispute_form").dialog({ height: 'auto' });
```

=== UPDATE ===

With auto height, resettet min-height and an additional close button:

```
$("#dispute_form").dialog({
    height: 'auto'
    , minHeight: '0'
    , buttons: {
        "Close": function() {
            $("#dispute_res").val("close");
            $("#dispute_form").dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

Also see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scessor/rLXyz/3/).

Comment: I tried following but it is giving error:  function CloseDisputeDialog() {        
        $("#dispute_form").html("@Html.Raw(closingMsg)");        
        $("#dispute_form").dialog("addbutton", "Close", { height: 'auto' }, function() {
            $("#dispute_res").val("close");             
            $("#dispute_form").dialog("close");            
        });

Comment: `function CloseDisputeDialog() { $("#dispute_form").html("@Html.Raw(closingMsg)"); $("#dispute_form").dialog({ height: 'auto' }); $("#dispute_form").dialog("addbutton", "Close", function() { $("#dispute_res").val("close"); $("#dispute_form").dialog("close"); });`

Comment: If you also want to reset the min-height use: `$("#dispute_form").dialog({ height: 'auto', minHeight: '0' });`. Also see my updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scessor/rLXyz/2/).

Comment: I have updated my answer. Now there should be auto height, resettet min-height and the additional close button.